# Is it possible for a player to gain the innate ability to regenerate body parts without spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, racial-traits, regeneration

Using the DMG's Injuries variant rule (or just having a character who for whatever reason is missing a body part), a character can lose an arm, leg, or eye, and the *regenerate* spell is the normal way to get it back. But if you don't have a party member that can cast that, finding someone who can could be quite a hassle. Hence, the question in the title.

*Ioun stones* are obvious targets for enemies, and a dragon could eat the arm carrying your *ring of regeneration*. Undying Warlocks get close with their 14th-level feature, but that only lets them reattach body parts, so if their arm does get eaten off, then they're stuck, too. The Armorer subclass for Artificers doesn't regrow limbs, but it basically gives you an always-on prosthetic limb for any arm or leg that you lose. Eyes (or any other scars or internal injuries), however, aren't "limbs". I can't find any other feature (and don't know of any race) that gets closer to the goal of regeneration without needing to rely on spells or magic items, other than just playing a monster campaign as a troll (AKA not something a "PC" is generally able to do)

Comment: the DMG (p. 139) states "Unless a ring's description says otherwise, a ring must be worn on a finger, or a similar digit, for the ring's magic to function". If your DM isn't anatomically well-versed, you could try to convince him/her that wearing a Ring of Regeneration on body parts that are ... less likely to get bitten off should work ^^ (I'm, of course, referring to toes. What else?)

Comment: Would casting a spell to gain this ability satisfy your requirements? It would be a one-time casting and boom you got the ability - if you have a nice DM.

Comment: @TobiasF. Which spell are you thinking of? Using *wish* is a bit of a stretch if you ask me (and apparently a few other people, too). (Thinking about it, *true polymorph* might technically answer the question as worded--beware *dispel magic* if you use that route, though) The question saying "without spells" was mostly because otherwise "be a cleric" is a valid answer, and I wasn't sure how to exclude stuff like that without the topic being wordy.

Comment: I thought of wish and kind of expected this kind of response, hence I asked

Comment: I'm curious: how did this come up? I've run role-playing for almost 50 years, and in DnD (well, I think it was ADnD 1) there was only one case where a player lost a hand. He cut it off himself so he could put a troll's hand on the stump. Of course, I'm a nice gm.

Comment: @NomadMaker Honestly it's mostly a flavorful precaution for someone who doesn't want to deal with the risk of suffering such devastating permanent damage. 5e does have a potentially extremely brutal injury variant rule, so it's definitely something that can happen in grittier campaigns. 3.5e's Troll Blooded feat saved me big time once, and basically made me a fan of passive regeneration effects for life, lol

Answer (score 8):

### Eat a troll.

... while there are no rules to support it, eating a willing troll with Varpak's blessing is the way Frost Giant Everlasting Ones (Volo's, p 147-8) gain their Regeneration ability.

Comment: ...and how would you propose to convince Vaprak to send you such a troll without being a Frost Giant to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, maybe

I see 3 options, but while they are published rules they rely a lot on the DM or are optional.

Cast Wish and wish for regeneration.
This involves a spell, but not to recover the limb, this is pre-cast and then permanent, assuming the DM grants the wish of course.

Reach level 21.
The epic boons presented in the DMG are examples, so getting regen at that level is perfectly within the bounds of power and rules. This is however an option on an optional rule, so also unreliable. Plus level 21, so not going to be common.

Gain a blessing. Published examples are in the DMG and some run similarly in power to permanent regeneration. Maybe do a dangerous quest for the troll god.

Comment: The question specifically asks for solutions that don't use spells. Additionally, there is no level 21, the DMG says explicitly: "An epic boon is a special power available only to 20th level characters." Further, there is no Boon of Regeneration or similar, so something like that would have to be homebrewed, and I'm pretty certain OP is not looking for homebrew.

Comment: @thomasmarkov that's a bit nitpicky on both fronts. Also the published boons are examples, which I mentioned specifically, so yes homebrew, but it is recommended homebrew, not just random. I mean I could just have answered no, but that's a bit boring. In fact this answer probably highlights how difficult it would be given the power level involved in gaining it.

Answer (score 1):

### There is nothing official, but that doesn't mean you can't make your own

There is no official content that allows regeneration without the use of spells or magic items. However, there are plenty of ways that you could homebrew easier ways to regrow lost body parts into the game, or even just build things into the world

The first way you could do this is probably the easiest, and that is to make healer npcs in towns. These healers would be able to be paid to cast healing spells that can regrow limbs

The second is a spell, and while I know you said you don't want spells, a lower level spell that's sole purpose is to regrow lost limbs and such would make it far easier to access, and could be used at far lower levels, and can factor into the first method

Third could be a blessing or charm of sorts. Perhaps as a reward for a quest, characters are each bestowed with a magical ability that will automatically regrow the next body part that the character loses.

A final means, though it is highly dependent on the setting, could be that magical devices exist that can be used to regrow lost body parts. This is somewhat similar to the first method, but it's something that the characters could carry around in their bags, and if lost could be bought again. This would however make most sense in a high technology kind of world setting, so it's a lot more world specific

Answer (score 0):

### There is no way to do this using only official content, and no spells

As of this date, there is no race/feat/class combination that allows a PC to regrow limbs without using spells.

 **UNLESS** you are willing to slightly bend your rules around "no spells" for the Circle of the Moon Druids level 14 feature, Thousand Forms, which allows them to cast *alter self* at will. This would allow them to alter themself to having the lost limb, but is *technically* a spell, even though it is more flavoured as an innate ability.
This is the only way I know of, as of RAW without spells/magic items.

Comment: Could I have feedback, whoever downvoted this?

Comment: I was not the downvoter, but... "your basic shape remains the same".  Alter Self does not do this thing that you want it to do.  It cannot give you back limbs you have lost.

Answer (score -1):

#### Circle of the Moon druid

This one's a bit of a dodge, but a Circle of the Moon druid generally spends most of their adventuring day in animal form anyway.  If the animal's leg gets torn off, it stops being an issue the next time you Wild Shape, and if the human's arm gets torn off... well, you're spending most of your day in animal form, right?

Then, once you get to 13th level, you can *be* the party member that casts regenerate.